# Linking Between Shells sh to ksh on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, symlink

```
ln -sf /bin/sh /bin/ksh cmd
```

will creates link from sh to ksh.
i.e:

```
/bin/ksh->/bin/sh
```

After creating Link, the commands will be executed on sh shell.

Here User will be executing commands on KSH shell, how we will get know that/how to Verify the commands which are Running on KShell will be executing on SH Shell.

Comment: you need to study `symlink` in linux.

Comment: @LuckyBoy, symlink i know, can u Plz provide me some details Related to Shell Link

Comment: Hi.. can u pleas share ideas, if you know anything related to  'Linking Between Shells sh to ksh on Linux'

Comment: what I understand that you want to replace sh shell with ksh shell. which means executing any command on sh will actually be executed in ksh. and on exiting ksh will be exit along with terminal window.
please look over [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202194/how-do-i-change-to-ksh)